# C# and ASP.Net. Guidance required

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a student and do my work and projects in c#.. I have not experienced WEB still. The question I wish to ask is that whenever in or near future if I wish to switch onto developing WEB Applications on ASP.Net, will I experience any difference ?? excluding any syntax changes.. I mean in C# the way do Add Update and Delete Records and the calculations, will I be experiencing the same in ASP.Net??

I don't have any concepts of WEB.I want to ask you people that what do you consider the most important to learn before switching onto ASP.Net?

Guide me please.. :/

Comment: Did you like one of these answers enough to flag it as accepted?

Comment: all of them are correct and knowledge able.. and i also have rated them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences in server-side code. 
The main different is in the UI. 
While Microsoft tries to maintain a UI experience similar to Windows applications using its custom controls and the designer, you need a good knowledge in HTML and CSS if you want to create complex UI tasks.

Custom controls actually **generate** client side code such as HTML, CSS and Javascript. 
So your main challenge will be the presentation layer and how to create client side code that is well parsed on different browsers. It's more difficult than Windows' "Drag and drop" technique, but it's quite a lot more powerful.

You'll notice that you can't drag and move controls the way you do with Windows apps, changing their coordinates on the screen.
HTML is not about coordinates, it's based on a certain document flow in manually defined layouts.

Don't be tempted by changing Web controls to absolute positioning, just because you think it's "easier". It's a mistake a lot of migrators to ASP.NET do, and it's generally a huge mistake that I suggest you don't fall into.

Comment: That's very good advice, regarding the "absolute positioning" mode of Visual Studio. Don't ever do it. What a horrible option MS gave developers with that. Just practice positioning your web objects with CSS.

Comment: While we're going there, I would add that you should be good with HTML and CSS, and probably decent with Javascript, at least to understand it, before you jump into ASP.NET development. Don't get hobbled by MS's coddling with ASP.NET drag and drop controls. If you get too used to the drag and drop, what you see is what you get mentality, you will have a harder time switching to developing as you should.

Comment: do you mean to say that while making custom controls, i need great practice on HTML for better UI.. is it?

Comment: No he means... Even when using Microsoft's or other custom controls, you should have a good understanding of HTML.

Comment: SiN: That's horrible advice. There's a massive difference in server-side code to desktop code. And while custom controls may generate JavaScript, they still rely on postbacks, which blows all stored values in YOUR other JavaScripts away. Once you start down that road, there's no turning back. Unfortunately, the scope of this error doesn't become evident soon enough, and when it does, it's usually too late.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the difference between Windows apps and Web apps, the most important and hardest thing will be for you to grasp the page life cycle. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for Microsofts overview.

Comment: i also wanted to ask that the way i code in c#, will there be any difference in implementing asp.net? or you mean to say that if i will understand the page life cycle, it will create the whole scenario different for me while coding

Comment: I think getting a grasp of the page life cycle will give you the "aha!" for ASP.NET development, and from there you will be able to build all your other knowledge. With that you will see how the C# coding is different between Windows forms and Web. The thing to remember is really this...all your C# code will be run on the server. Then the server will send the info to the users browser to create the web page. When the user interacts with the web page, it sends information to the server, which then runs some more of your C# code, and responds with more information for the browser, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the web and desktop applications have considerable difference. The one and most important is that when on Web there are two states of WEB application

1. On Server side : where we have C# code and stuff.
2. Client side : Where we have CSS, HTML and JavaScript doing it all for us.

Besides this HTTP which is communication bridge.

This is one big different that desktop application developer face when they switch to the Web Applications.

I will suggest you to take a look at basics of CSS, HTML and JavaScript while swiching on web applications. That really helps in log term.

Comment: well Anil Namde.. I have a little knowledge of CSS, HTML and aswell as of Javascript.. Your Answer was knowledgeable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd say if you look into web application, make a few quick examles with ASP.NET WebForms, and then a few with ASP.NET MVC, to learn the differences between good design (MVC with AJAX and without postbacks) and bad design (quick and dirty WebForms with postbacks and without AJAX).

Try using JavaScript on pages, and look at how postbacks reset all JS variables, and the impact that has on anything dynamic. Also look at how postbacks exponentially increase the complexity (and bugs, such as session timeouts with label text stored in session) and decrease the debugability of your application.

Take a look at JQuery, JQuery uploadify and JQuery Treeview, and JQuery DataTable, and JQuery Charts.

Add and UpdateRecords imply editing a DataTable and saving the changes.
This is the worst thing you can possibly get your hands in with ASP.NET, that is, if you want to do it properly (with the possible exception of asynchronous data processing).

Answer (score 0):

If you are really passionate to dive into web application development especially ASP.NET, I would recommend the following path for a beginner to kick start with.

1. Start learning [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp), [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)
2. Next you could try Classical [ASP](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp). Having a know how of classical ASP will definitely be a plus, when moving to ASP.NET because, you will under stand how ASP.NET renders pages and what ASP.NET controls really does etc etc. In my own words ASP.NET is a chocolate coated version of classical ASP, I am telling this from my classical ASP experience.
3. Next you need to firm understanding of on how the [web works and its internals](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/). If you need you could also refresh on [How Internet works](http://www.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet.htm) and [How website works](http://www.howstuffworks.com/web-page.htm) ([this too](http://www.techcuriosity.com/resources/curiosity/how_website_work.php)).
4. Finally you could start off with ASP.NET 2.0 and later move to advanved stuff like AJAX, MVC etc.
5. You could further enhance you skill by learning jQuery and some CMS (Content Management Tools) like DotnetNuke.